# How to copy object's name to that same object's Geometry Nodes modifier's object input with Python?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/JXy1i4Gu8NQ?t=104) and it requires some intense manual labor in the section where the video starts in the link.

How can I copy object's name to that same object's Geometry Nodes modifier's object input with Python?

[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't work but also doesn't give an error:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        bpy.data.objects[obj.name].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_5"] == obj.name
```

Comment: Good question, AFAICT you can not assign something to those exposed properties at the moment (Blender 2.93.4). However, you can assign the object to the *Object* slot of the *Group Input* node though, see: https://pasteall.org/248b/raw but the assignment isn't reflected in the modifiers panel for whatever reason...

Comment: @brockmann Thanks! Too bad :/

Comment: No problem. You can assign it to the *Object Info* node, but that wouldn't be that flexible...

Comment: Yes, might be no good if the object needs to be different but the nodes-structure only the one and not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable *Python Tooltips* in the user preferences.

[image]

Then, hover your mouse over the field and note the integer that's displayed in the tooltip.

In my case it's $2$.

[image]

Then you can access this fields like so :

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
modifier = obj.modifiers.get("GeometryNodes")  # Case sensitive
input_name = "Input_2"
modifier[input_name] = obj
```

Run the script :

[image]

You may need to hover your mouse over the modifier properties for the field value to update in the interface.